# Why are there difrences between the tsconfig documantaion and the tsconfig file that `tsc --init` generate?

Tags: typescript, configuration, documentation

The [`tsconfig` documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) includes all (I think) the possible properties that can exist in a `.tsconfig` file.
when running the `tsc --init` command, the config file that is being generated doesn't include all these properties.

In addition, there is [this file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1f85123821455dbfd464eedce854d09c3e41a1d4/tests/baselines/reference/tsConfig/Default%20initialized%20TSConfig/tsconfig.json) from the typescript Github repo that includes many properties that also don't exist on the config file that is being generated when running the `tsc --init` command.

So my question is why isn't `tsc --init` generate a config file with all the properties?
Why does this inconsistency exist between these 3 sources:

1. [tsconfig documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig).
2. [Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/1f85123821455dbfd464eedce854d09c3e41a1d4/tests/baselines/reference/tsConfig/Default%20initialized%20TSConfig/tsconfig.json).
3. The file generated with `tsc --init`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Configuration exists to help you change how typescript compiles your files. If there are configurations you don't need, then you simply don't include them.

`tsc` offers you a basic initial configuration which does not assume too much about your use case. If you want to make more changes, then add more configuration options as needed; that's why the *documentation* exists.